# xcode project-/target-settings-syntax for linker flag force_load on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, linker

I am confronted with the double bind. On the one hand, for one of the 3rd party static libraries my iPhone application uses, the linker flag `-all_load` has to be set in the application project or target settings. Otherwise, the app crashes at run-time not finding some symbols called internally from the lib. On the other hand, for another 3rd party static lib, `-all_load` must not be set on application level, or the app won't build thanks to a "duplicate symbols" linker error.

To solve this issue, I now want to use `force_load` instead of `load_all`, as it due to documentation it does the same like `all_load`, but only for the passed path or lib-file, instead of all libs.

The problem with `force_load` is, I do not have a clue how to pass a path or file as parameter with it, when passing it via XCode project- or target-settings. All syntax-possibilities I tried either lead xcode to thinking it's another linker flag instead of a parameter to the previous one, or the linker throwing syntax related errors, or the flag simply does nothing at all.

I also opened the .pbxproj-file in a text-editor to edit it to the correct command line syntax manually. But when reloading the project with XCode, it auto-changes the syntax into interpreting the parameter to `force_load` as a separate flag.

Anyone have an idea on this issue?

Comment: bounty for anyone who can show how to get force_load to work.  Basically, some of the libraries to my project need to be linked with all_load; others need to be linked without it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I just tried this.  I've compiled a static armv6, armv7, and i386 fat binary of PCRE for use in my iPhone project.  My project normally just has my library added to the project and that links fine.  So I unchecked the target membership box for libpcre.a and rebuilt.  As expected, I get a bunch of missing symbol linker errors for the pcre symbols.  Then I opened the target settings window and edited the "Other Linker Flags" section.  I added:

```
-force_load lib/pcre/libpcre.a
```

The `lib` directory is in the same directory as my project.xcodeproj file.

It linked fine so I know the force_load command worked (and I can see it added to the build flags when xcode builds the file).

Hope that helps.

Update:

I also tried adding a system library to the "Other Linker Flags" line like so:

```
-force_load src/pcre/libpcre.a -force_load ${SDKROOT}/usr/lib/libz.dylib
```

That worked too.

Comment: Hmmmm, I have a library with categories.  If I link it with all_load, everything is great.  If I link it without all_load, it links OK, but on run it has errors when it tries to call category methods.  If I link it with force_load directoryPath/release-iOS-internal-iphonesimulator/libraryname.a, I get a duplicate symbol error.  The version I am building is the debug version; could that have anything to do with it?

Comment: The force_load command is including your library. If you have a duplicate symbol error then you probably really do have a duplicate symbol in there somewhere. I'm not sure if this would cause a problem but is the library included as a member of your project and also via force_load? Maybe that makes a difference with categories. Do you have a category method with the same name already defined in your project somewhere? You can also look at the build results window in xcode, select 'show all messages', then pop down the link command to get the command line then go play with that in terminal.

Comment: According to http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/Upgrade-your-PhoneGap-Xcode-Template-for-3rd-Party-Library-Linkage-Problems, it does appear that you're using the flag correctly. My guess would also be that you have a class or category with the same name as one in the library you're linking...

Comment: The weird thing is that it shows the symbol conflicting with itself at the same path. The error message looks like this:  

ld: duplicate symbol  _OBJC_IVAR_$_WKBiPhoneKeyboardLayoutView._currentKeyTimer in /path/file and /path/file.  

The path and file names are identical.

Comment: That is weird but I have no idea.  You'll have to look at the command line that is being passed to the linker and see if you can manually tweak things on the command line until you get a viable build configuration.  If all else fails you may have to file a support request with Apple DTS.

Comment: Double-check that the file is not compiled into both the library and some other object, such as another library or your application. Is it possible both libraries have statically linked the same third library or included the same third-party source code?

Comment: I now have this working, provided I use an absolute path.  If I use a relative path, the linker appears to think that the file with the absolute path and the file with the relative path are different files and therefore to find conflicts between the file and itself.  If I always use absolute paths, these problems go away.  This is still not really a satisfactory solution -- see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787279/xcode-get-force-load-to-work-with-relative-paths)

Answer (score 1):

I just added force_load to our project and all is fine using the simplest syntax possible. The library is a dependency built in the same project. The library is therefore included on the link command-line twice: once as a normal input file and once as an argument to -force_load. You might want to put quote characters around the argument.

In fact, I've even got this working using configuration-dependent settings (because the path is obviously different for debug vs. release and device vs. simulator).

Good luck.

Comment: Actually the reason, that force_load was not working for me, was, that I added quotes. Removing the quotes lead into Xcode splitting it up into two lines, but makes it working, when being passed from the IDE to the compiler. With quotes it is correctly displayed in the IDE, but the compiler can't handle it that way.