# Cocos2d MenuItemLabel using Blocks causes SIGABRT

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, objective-c-blocks

In Cocos2D using blocks to create a menu action causes a `SIGABRT` error in that scene's `init` method:

```
 CCLabelTTF *label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"test" fontName:@"Times" fontSize:12];
 CCMenuItemLabel *toCauseCrash = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:label block:^(id sender) {
  NSLog(@"Blocks work?");
}];
```

Tried the newest Cocos2D, nothing. [This forum post](http://cocos2d-central.com/topic/622-ccmenuitemfont-using-block-have-error/) promises (a) a hotfix soon, and an edit to the "BuildSettings-iOS.xcconfig" file (which doesn't exist, as far as I can tell).

(1) Does anyone know how to fix Cocos2D to allow blocks in menus?

<s>(2) Does anyone know what xcconfig file the above post is talking about, or how to find it?</s> (That's a Kobold2d thing)

Edit: here are the code examples I've tried after setting "-force_load $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/" in OTHER_LINKER_FLAGS:

```
id blockAction = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
  NSLog(@"Blocks action");
}];

void (^reusableBlock)(id sender) = ^(id sender) {
  NSLog(@"Reusable block");
};
// SIGABRT:
CCMenuItemLabel *menuItem = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:myLabel block:blockAction];
// SIGABRT:
CCMenuItemLabel *menuItem = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:myLabel block:reusableBlock];
```

Comment: i had problems with blocks in menuItem that prevent the item to be correctly released when parent is deallocated. My suggestion would be to not using block in MenuItems for now and stick with the target: selector:

Comment: @Ultrakorne yep, that's the problem I'm describing. I'm hoping to solve the problem. In the meantime, yep, I am using that workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like for right now the answer is: Blocks are problematic, even when you use -force_load on the cocos2d lib. I will be super happy for the day there is a different answer I can accept on this question.

Answer (score 0):

The forum post refers to [Kobold2D](http://www.kobold2d.com). But the same issue does apply if you're building cocos2d into a static library, although there will not be any .xcconfig files. In that case you will have to [-force_load your cocos2d lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787279/xcode-get-force-load-to-work-with-relative-paths) in order to use the CCMenu blocks by adding this to the "Other Linker Flags" section in the Build Settings.

Another issue to watch out for is of course that your Deployment Target must be set to iOS 4.0 or higher. Blocks are not available in iOS 3.x.

Comment: Thanks for this-- tried it but still get SIGABRT whenever I use a block. (Editing post to provide code since it won't format properly here.)