# NSURL urlWithSpotifyLink: unrecognized selector sent to class Spotify iPhone error

Tags: spotify

The Spotify iPhone app I was working on, was running fine, but now I keep on getting this error:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSURL urlWithSpotifyLink:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1e7621c`

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [CocoaLibSpotify readme](https://github.com/spotify/cocoalibspotify/), you need to add the `-ObjC` and `-all_load` flags to the "Other Linker Flags" build setting in Xcode.

Comment: Yep, thanks. Also, don't be so fast to down vote. I am using the Parse framework in my application and apparently having these settings in the XCode project don't play nice with the Parse framework: as in, the project does not build with these flags and Parse.

Comment: I dunno why people downvoted - I certainly didn't. Anyway, these flags are linker flags, not compiler flags, so they shouldn't affect compilation at all.

Comment: Or you can use `-force_load` for just spotify, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5095793/193896