# Apple Mach-O Linker Error - ld: file not found: -ObjC

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, clang

I've inherited an iOS project and can't even get it to build. I keep getting the following error:

```
ld: file not found: -ObjC
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've seen posts about the 'file not found' error but none pertaining to the '-ObjC' bit that looks like a switch.

Any ideas?

Comment: mention your problem in detail. what framework you are using or etc. because this type of error come with many causes. like framework missing or not set header properly etc.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how best to answer.

The deployment target is iOS 6.1.

The following frameworks are listed in 'General': SystemConfiguration, Security, CoreData, CoreGraphics, CoreLocation, MapKit, UIKit, Foundation, QuartzCore, MessageUI.

The following are also listed but in red: libGMDatePicker.a (I think this is an internal one), libCascade.a, libBCTabBarController.a, libFlurry.a, libPods.a

They're all required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone, I managed to sort it.

@Droppy pointed me in the right direction.

Before the `-ObjC` flag there was another called `-force_all`. I then stumbled across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5095793/1123511%20this%20answer) which indicated that you only need the `-ObjC` flag. I removed `-force_all` and it started to work!

Answer (score 2):

`-ObjC` is a valid option to `ld`, however it's possible to confuse `ld` if some other option is broken.  For example the `-framework` option requires an argument and if that argument (the name of the framework) is missing then that would cause the sort of error you are seeing.

```
ld ... -framework -ObjC
```

However I cannot tell you exactly where the error is without seeing the complete linker command line.

Answer (score 0):

Look through your build settings, both in Xcode and in xcconfig file.

I have seen people adding an option - ObjC to some build settings for no good reason at all, and the linker may interpret that as a request to link a file named ObjC or -ObjC.