# -all_load other linker flag causing duplicate symbol errors in 3rd party framework

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a static library we use for in-house apps that contains some common utility code. From previous SO posts, I have found that in order to get categories in the static library to be loaded at run-time, I need to include `-all_load -ObjC` in the Other Linker Flags field in Build Settings.

However, with a closed-source, 3rd party library that I am also using, if I use these flags, I get several duplicate symbol errors. I have verified that I can get the app to build by taking these flags out, but of course, at runtime I get unrecognized selector crashes when using category methods.

Is there any way to target the `-all_load -ObjC` to only be applied to my static library, somehow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the -force_load flag instead

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354864/xcode-project-target-settings-syntax-for-linker-flag-force-load-on-iphone) post for more details.